# Autoincrement in Entity Framework 5 without identity column in database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have not been able to find any appropriate solution for my problem, so here's my question for you:

In Entity Framework (5.0), how can I setup an ID-column (PK) to be autocremented when no identity column is defined in the actual database (SQL Server 2005)?

I have seen the StoreGeneratedPattern, but not sure how this would work without identity in the db. The manual approach would be to manually populate the POCO with MAX(id)+1, but that feels like a hack and I'm worried that it will introduce problems in a multi-threaded environment where multiple requests may insert records to my table at the "same" time.

Note that I do not have the possibility to alter the table schema in the database.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: why are you not wanting to use an identity column in the first place?

Comment: Of course I would like to use an identity column, but I cannot change the table structure in the database due to several reasons, e.g. this would break functionality in other software that I cannot control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one instance of your application is the only thing inserting rows into this table, then the `MAX(Id) + 1` hack is probably good enough. Otherwise, you'll need to alter the database schema to generate these values on insert -- either by using IDENTITY or by re-inventing the wheel using triggers, sprocs, etc.

Whatever your solution, it should guarantee that a duplicate key will never be generated -- even if a transaction happens to rollback one or more inserts.

If nothing else inserts into the table, you should be able to alter Id to an identity column without breaking compatibility.

**FYI:** Entity Framework's `StoreGeneratedPattern` (or `DatabaseGeneratedOption`) only specifies how values are handled on insert and update. Using `Identity` tells EF that the value is expected to be generated by the database on insert. `Computed` means it's generated on both insert and update.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification Brice, it was kind of as I expected. The "MAX(id)+1 hack" will then not be sufficient in my case, as serveral instances of my application may do inserts to this table.  


**Idea:** What if I move all the logic from application code into a stored procedure and do the "MAX(id) +1" within a transaction, do you think that will be sufficient, or do I need to put some kind of lock on the table?

Comment: @anve, I'm not sure what the best approach would be. Personally, I would investigate more into exactly what breaks by adding IDENTITY to the column. You may want to ask a new question targeted just at the SQL Server community; EF doesn't seem to be a relevant piece of the puzzle anymore.